# Can I still be tracked if I spoofed my MAC address?

Tags: wireless, mac-address

Supposing I Spoofed my MAC address using Kali Linux macchanger then using aircrack to hack in a router. What kind of footprint will I be leaving behind? Will I still be tracked?

I am not sure if this question is appropriate for this site. If its inappropriate for this site, could you direct me to an appropriate site where I can ask such questions.

There is a [CodeBreaker](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90597/codebreakers-codehackers-hackoverflow) stackexchange, but its still in definition stage.

Comment: Questions about "_bypassing network security or policies_" are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. NE is a site to ask and provide answers about professionally managed networks. The community has decided that questions about bypassing network security or policies are off topic . Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you do on a network can be recorded, correlated, and ultimately traced. (see also: TOR users being exposed) The longer you sit on someone else's network the more likely they are to take notice.

Comment: It's the same thing I assume as soon as I cross the Las Vegas city limits. Everything is monitored 24x7. :)